# pyspark - difference between select and agg

Tags: select, pyspark, group-by, aggregate

What is the difference between the following two -

`df.select(min("salary")).show()`

and

`df.agg({'salary':'min'}).show()`

Also, what is the difference in these two -

`df.groupBy("department").agg({'salary':'min'}).show()`

and

`df.groupBy("Company").min('salary').show()`

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, there are many different ways to write the same thing. It depends mostly if you prefer a SQL writting or a python writting.

`df.select(min("salary"))` is the equivalent of SQL :

```sql
select min(salary) from df
```

This query computes the min of the column `salary` without any group by clause.
It is equivalent to

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy().agg(F.min("salary"))

# OR

df.groupBy().agg({'salary':'min'})
```

As you can see, the `groupBy` is empty, so you do not group by anything. Python also can interpret the dict `{'salary':'min'}` which is equivalent to the function `F.min("salary")`.

The method `agg` depends on the object. Applied to a [`Dataframe`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg), it is equivalent to `df.groupBy().agg`. `agg` is also a method of the object [`GroupedData`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg) which is created when you do `df.groupBy()`. I added the link to the officiel doc where you can see the difference between the two methods.

When writting `df.groupBy("department").agg({'salary':'min'})`, you can specify in the method `agg` several different aggregation. When using just `min`, you are limited to one column. For example, you can do this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 

df.groupBy("department").agg(F.min("salary"), F.max("age"))

# OR

df.groupBy("department").agg({'salary':'min', 'age':'max'})

# But you cannot do 

df.groupBy("department").min("salary").max("age")
>> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'max'
```